# tailwind, nuxt webstrom - intellisense not working in dev mode

Tags: nuxt.js, intellisense

I have set up a project with nuxt.js and tailwindcss.
While running nuxt in dev mode no auto completion is available.
In the .nuxt folder aren't any .css files or something equally.
If I run nuxt build there are css files generated into the .nuxt folder and intellisense is working.
After running npm run dev again the .nuxt folder gets refreshed, the css files are removed and the intellisense isn't working anymore.

I got a workaround with copying the builded css files into a project folder but there aren't uptodate if i change my tailwind.config.js.

Is there a way to setup nuxt and tailwind correctly so autocomplete works in dev mode?

Thank for helping.

Edit:
Tailwind config is without purge.

Nuxt config:

```
module.exports = {
  // Global page headers: https://go.nuxtjs.dev/config-head
  server: {
    port: process.env.NUXT_SERVER_PORT, // default: 3000
    host: "localhost", // default: localhost,
    timing: false
  },
  head: {
    title: "Title",
    htmlAttrs: {
      lang: "en"
    },
    meta: [
      { charset: "utf-8" },
      {
        name: "viewport",
        content: "width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1"
      },
      {
        name: "apple-mobile-web-app-status-bar-style",
        content: "default"
      },
      { hid: "description", name: "description", content: "" }
    ],
    link: [
      { rel: "icon", type: "image/x-icon", href: "/favicon.svg" },
      {
        rel: "apple-touch-icon",
        type: "image/png",
        href: "/icon.png"
      }
    ]
  },

  // Nuxt PWA module config; https://pwa.nuxtjs.org/meta
  pwa: {
    meta: {
      "apple-mobile-web-app-capable": true,
      "apple-mobile-web-app-status-bar-style": "default", //apparently does nothing with ios11
      name: "name",
      author: "author",
      description: "description",
      lang: "de",
      theme_color: "#5423F8",
      favicon: true
    },
    manifest: {
      name: "name",
      lang: "de",
      description: "description"
    },
    icon: {
      purpose: ["any"]
    }
  },

  // Global CSS: https://go.nuxtjs.dev/config-css
  css: ["~/assets/scss/base.scss"],

  // Plugins to run before rendering page: https://go.nuxtjs.dev/config-plugins
  plugins: [
    { src: "~/plugins/axios.js", ssr: true },
    "~/plugins/vee-validate.js"
  ],

  // Auto import components: https://go.nuxtjs.dev/config-components
  components: [
    "~/components/",
    "~/components/base/",
    "~/components/nav/",
    "vue-inline-svg"
  ],

  // Modules for dev and build (recommended): https://go.nuxtjs.dev/config-modules
  buildModules: [
    "@nuxtjs/tailwindcss",
    "@nuxtjs/composition-api/module",
    "@nuxtjs/dotenv",
    "@nuxtjs/pwa"
  ],

  // Modules: https://go.nuxtjs.dev/config-modules
  modules: [
    // https://go.nuxtjs.dev/axios
    "@nuxtjs/axios",
    "@nuxtjs/firebase",
    "cookie-universal-nuxt"
  ],
  // Axios module configuration: https://go.nuxtjs.dev/config-axios
  axios: {
    baseURL: "http://localhost:8080/api", //fallback
    credentials: true
  },

  publicRuntimeConfig: {
    axios: {
      baseURL: process.env.EXPRESS_SERVER_URL
    }
  },

  privateRuntimeConfig: {
    axios: {
      baseURL: process.env.EXPRESS_SERVER_URL
    }
  },

  auth: {
    persistence: "local",
    initialize: {
      onAuthStateChangedAction: "onAuthStateChangedAction",
      onAuthStateChangedMutation: "ON_AUTH_STATE_CHANGED_MUTATION",
      subscribeManually: false
    },
    ssr: true,
    emulatorPort: 9099,
    emulatorHost: "https://localhost"
  },

  // Build Configuration: https://go.nuxtjs.dev/config-build
  build: {
    extractCSS: true,
    transpile: ["vee-validate/dist/rules"]
  }
};
```

package.json

```
{
  "name": "name",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "nuxt",
    "build": "nuxt build",
    "start": "nuxt start",
    "generate": "nuxt generate",
    "lint:js": "eslint --ext \".js,.vue\" --ignore-path .gitignore .",
    "lint": "npm run lint:js"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@nuxtjs/axios": "^5.13.1",
    "@nuxtjs/composition-api": "^0.24.1",
    "@nuxtjs/dotenv": "^1.4.1",
    "@nuxtjs/firebase": "^7.5.0",
    "cookie-universal-nuxt": "^2.1.4",
    "core-js": "^3.9.1",
    "filepond": "^4.28.2",
    "filepond-plugin-file-validate-type": "^1.2.6",
    "filepond-plugin-image-crop": "^2.0.6",
    "filepond-plugin-image-exif-orientation": "^1.0.11",
    "filepond-plugin-image-preview": "^4.6.7",
    "filepond-plugin-image-resize": "^2.0.10",
    "filepond-plugin-image-transform": "^3.8.6",
    "filepond-plugin-image-validate-size": "^1.2.6",
    "firebase": "^8.6.3",
    "flatted": "^3.1.1",
    "imagesloaded": "^4.1.4",
    "jwt-decode": "^3.1.2",
    "lodash": "^4.17.21",
    "masonry-layout": "^4.2.2",
    "moment": "^2.29.1",
    "nuxt": "^2.15.6",
    "nuxt-dropzone": "^1.0.4",
    "swiper": "^6.7.0",
    "vee-validate": "^3.4.9",
    "vue-awesome-swiper": "^4.1.1",
    "vue-filepond": "^6.0.3",
    "vue-inline-svg": "^2.0.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@nuxtjs/eslint-config": "^6.0.0",
    "@nuxtjs/eslint-module": "^3.0.2",
    "@nuxtjs/pwa": "^3.3.5",
    "@nuxtjs/tailwindcss": "^4.1.2",
    "@tailwindcss/jit": "^0.1.18",
    "autoprefixer": "^10.2.6",
    "babel-eslint": "^10.1.0",
    "eslint": "^7.22.0",
    "eslint-plugin-nuxt": "^2.0.0",
    "eslint-plugin-vue": "^7.7.0",
    "node-sass": "^6.0.1",
    "postcss": "^8.3.0",
    "prettier": "1.19.1",
    "sass-loader": "^10.2.0",
    "tailwindcss": "^2.2.2"
  }
}
```

Comment: Hi, can you please provide a [repro] and try to give us some more visuals details. Also, do you have a colleague with the same issue?

Comment: What kind of example do you need? The nuxt config or tailwind config?
Yes a colleague has the same problem.

Comment: Any relevant info that could help anybody here actually, more info here: [ask].